# Flash / AS3 Google Maps API (deprecated?)

Tags: javascript, android, actionscript-3, google-maps, air

Since Google Maps for Flash is deprecated ([see this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/)), what is the alternative. On the link posted it says that you should use the Javascript API, but what if your app doesn't have access to Javascript (as in an AIR based app for Android)? Or should I still use the deprecated one?

Comment: Yah it's bogus i used that one quite a bit, for a while.  You can probably use open street maps or mapquest APIs still, I believe both have a Flash/Flex library.  Otherwise you could probably use a StageWebView and the javascript API and something like this http://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/wiki/Communication.

Comment: so you used it and now it doesn't work? it seems like a pretty huge library to let it go deprecated without an alternative. hoping it's just not true. making me feel like i shouldn't be writing my app in AS3 and should just stick with an html mobile solution, or even writing a native app.

Comment: Apps built with the Flash Maps API will continue to work for the next couple of years at least, until the 3 year deprecation period ends. However, no new keys are being issued. If you can open a webview of some kind, you can access the JavaScript API. There's also and Android Map View, and a Static Maps API if you just want a basic image of the a map.

Comment: As @ManoMarks said it still works for the time being so it's not like they pulled the rug out from under us, but yah I would suggest looking at alternatives, both the MapQuest API and the Open Street Maps are pretty comparable to Google maps.  The alternative like you said is to look at building this as a HTML based web-app, something like Sencha touch (appcelerator, couple others out there) that will probably help.  I'm not running scared from AS3 but it's good to be aware one day it might go away (true of all programming languages but some are more resilient to time than others).

Comment: @Mano Marks - good to know that it will still work. -shaunhusain yeah i'd like to use a javascript framework because i'd be guaranteed that it will always be supported but unfortunately the responsiveness of the UI in html based frameworks can't compare to native apps. who knows though, maybe i'd be willing to sacrifice some of the responsiveness for cross-device compatibility and the assurance that the libraries will be heavily used and supported. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though the answer is to continue to use the deprecated AS3 Google Maps API until there is a viable alternative.